# Blackberry JDE 6.0 VERIFIER ERROR And KXML 2

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to import kxml2, what I did is I downloaded the lib, went to Project Explorer -> Properties -> Build Path -> Libraries, I include the kxml2-2.3.0.jar. I run compile and get this error

JAR file creation failed with error -1
The preverified classes if any are in tmp25754. See jar log of errors in C:\Users\sgil\AppData\Local\Temp\rapc_1296da5f.dir\jarlog.txt 
Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse-Blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components ...

Packaging project **** failed (took 0.795 seconds) 
Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse-Blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components ...
Packaging project **** failed (took 0.795 seconds)

I tried running the preverifier and I got this:

preverify -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse-B
lackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\lib\net_ri
m_api.jar" "C:\Users\sgil\Desktop\Projects\Blackberry****\lib\kxml2-2.3.0.
jar"

I get this error:

JAR file creation failed with error -1
The preverified classes if any are in tmp25503. See jar log of errors in output\
jarlog.txt

Any advice?

Comment: What is in the jarlog.txt file?

Comment: Error: No such file or directory
jar -cfm "output\kxml2-2.3.0.jar" tmp25503\\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF -C tmp25503 .

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to put the correct **PATH** variable in the "Enviromental Variables" of the System(right click in My PC->Enviromental Variables).

If "PATH" already exists you need to add the path of the BIN of the JDK installed on the Computer.

The carpet you should add this is the bin:

for example: `C:\PATH_TO_THE_INSTALLED_JDK\bin`